# How to use textbox value as an SQL connection string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.net in creating this application. My idea is when the main form loaded, there is another form with textboxes for the user to initialize connection to the sql server, and use that textbox value in calling the database for query.

Now, my problem is then main form closes the value in the textbox will be erased, and i have to type it again. When connecting for an SQL Server over the LAN, does it have the same process?

Comment: So, you want to put the success of your app at the tender mercies of an end user?  Why not have them pick from a list of DBNames like {Recipes, BabyNames, Historical Dates, Pretty Colors} then your code selects the appropriate (valid) connection string

Comment: Sorry to use the word "user", i am really new to programming. what i mean is how can i save the textbox value and to initialize a database connection and use that value as permanent connection string. in case the applicationn closes the value is still there. or another approach but  something like that idea

Comment: Have you heard of an app.config? The connection string has no business being exposed in the application.

Comment: @SeanLange i heard that bro. but i still don't know how to use it, really new in programming bro.

Comment: Your app needs to have all the valid connection strings at the outset.  It would be the job of the app to pick the correct one based on some selection.  it ought not be up to users to type in `Server=XXXX;Database=YYYY;User Id=AAAA; Password=BBBB;`  It is the job of the app to abstract and simplify those sorts of things

Comment: @SeanLange that really depends on the application; unless your application relies on support staff that are trained to manually edit configuration files (which it shouldn't), there should be some settings UI to make configuration easy, and validate that it is coherent. (Like a db connection string textbox with associated controls to test connectivity.)

Comment: @Plutonix that could just move their problem, as it then becomes a question of "how do I allow users to configure additional connections AND name them".

Comment: @Uueerdo i think you got my point of using some sort of UI for the developer or administrator to input the correct connection string for the new installation of the application. but that UI is hidden or restricted from the end user.

Comment: @Kemmy administrator can be a type of end user, and agree it should be a restricted user; but can dive into a deep topic of user management, permission systems, security, etc...; all that said, I just voted to close as the question is really way too broad. OP would probably better off looking into "getting values from forms" and "saving setting values".

Comment: @Uueerdo that approach is great bro. using that save value in the textboxes to initialize database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be referencing controls' values for logical uses like that; instead use the value in the control to populate a more persistent program entity, such as a settings object.

In your particular case, with VB.net (and presumably WinForms), showing connection form with ShowDialog() allows the form to persist after it has been closed. You can add a public property to the form to expose the user-entered value to the code that called it, and DialogResult of OK when the user indicates the value is accepted (usually through a button click).

*I'd provide a code example, but I've been deep in C# for more than a few months now and my VB.Net is getting rusty.*